# Cannot ID of element in DIV of jQuery accordion

Tags: jquery, find, accordion

My accordion looks like this:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <h3 id= '@Model[i].UserId'>@Model[i].UserName</h3>
            <div >
                @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model[i].UserId, new { @id = "txtId" + i })
                <table style="font-size:xx-small">
                    <tr>
                         <td>
                                            <img id='img + @Model[i].UserId' alt="" class="image" />
                                        </td>
```

This establishes the id for image element different from the ID of the H3 header.  I can get the ID of the header like this:

```
 $("#accordion > h3").click(function () {
        var currentID = $('.ui-accordion-header-active').attr('id');
        var divid = "#" + currentID;
        var imgId = $(divid).find(".image").attr("id");
        imgId = $('.ui-accordion-header-active .image').attr("id");
        alert(imgId);
    });
```

But I just cannot get the ID of image element.  What am I doing wrong?  I do not want to load any picture until the person is clicked in the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `.find` to get the `id` of the image where as `.find` tries to get the `children` of the selector referred. So you need to add one more `.next` to get `children` from that `div` as below, since `.image` rests inside `div` next to your `header`:

```
$("#accordion > h3").click(function () {
        var currentID = $('.ui-accordion-header-active').attr('id');
        var divid = "#" + currentID;
        var imgId = $(divid).next().find(".image").attr("id"); //.next here
        alert(imgId);
});
```

Again even the below line tries to find for children `.image` inside `header`

```
imgId = $('.ui-accordion-header-active .image').attr("id");
```

and I don't think you need this anymore in the above `event` so I just removed it..